# The distribution of chord lengths in a circle, Bertrand paradox

Tags: matlab, statistics, geometry

I want to write a program which will calculate the statistic in [Bertrand paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_%28probability%29).

In my way, I want select two dot in circle , and pass line using them (two dots), it is my chord. Then I want to calculate how many of these chords are longer than sqrt(3); but when I run this script some of the chords are bigger than 2 ! ( radius of my circle is 1 ) 
I don't know what is wrong with it, can anybody help me?

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122380/length-of-tendon-in-circle) link please for the formula used.

```
r1 = rand(1,1000000);
teta1 = 2*pi * rand(1,1000000);
x1 = r1 .* (cos(teta1));
y1 = r1 .* (sin(teta1));

r2 = rand(1,1000000);
teta2 = 2*pi * rand(1,1000000);
x2 = r2 .* (cos(teta2));
y2 = r2 .* (sin(teta2));
%solve this equation : solve('(t*x2 +(1-t)*x1)^2 +(t*y2 +(1-t)*y1)^2 =1', 't');
t1= ((- x1.^2.*y2.^2 + x1.^2 + 2*x1.*x2.*y1.*y2 - 2*x1.*x2 - x2.^2.*y1.^2 + x2.^2 + y1.^2 - 2*y1.*y2 + y2.^2).^(1/2) - x1.*x2 - y1.*y2 + x1.^2 + y1.^2)/(x1.^2 - 2*x1.*x2 + x2.^2 + y1.^2 - 2*y1.*y2 + y2.^2);
t2= -((- x1.^2.*y2.^2 + x1.^2 + 2*x1.*x2.*y1.*y2 - 2*x1.*x2 - x2.^2.*y1.^2 + x2.^2 + y1.^2 - 2*y1.*y2 + y2.^2).^(1/2) + x1.*x2 + y1.*y2 - x1.^2 - y1.^2)/(x1.^2 - 2*x1.*x2 + x2.^2 + y1.^2 - 2*y1.*y2 + y2.^2);

length = abs (t1-t2) * sqrt (( x2-x1).^2 + (y2-y1).^2);
hist(length)
flag = 0;
for check = length
if( check > sqrt(3) )
flag = flag + 1;
end
end

prob = (flag/1000000)^2;
```

Comment: Hand-calc what the roots are for a given set of x and y points, then check that your maths for `t1,t2` is right.  (At first glance, it can't be, because I don't see where you've taken into account the `=1` part).   You also say you want to "select two dot in circle", but your code will not limit the points picked to those within a circle of radius 1 centred on the origin, so in some cases the points you picked will not form a line which goes through the circle.

Comment: why do you say I don't limit it? rand in first line give 1000000 , in [0,1] . and also I solved my equation with x^2 +y^2 " =1" :-? @nkjt

Comment: sorry, I misread.  In that case, it must be your `t1/t2` calc that's the issue.

Comment: what is wrong with it? how can i make it correct? @nkjt

Answer (score 1):

Your formula for `length` is probably to blame for the nonsensical results, and  given its length, it is easier to replace it than to debug. Here is another way to find the length of chord passing through two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2):

1. Find the distance of the chord from the center
2. Use the Pythagorean theorem to find its length

In Matlab code, this is done by

```
distance = abs(x1.*y2-x2.*y1)./sqrt((x2-x1).^2+(y2-y1).^2);
length = 2*sqrt(1-distance.^2);
```

The formula for distance involves `abs(x1.*y2-x2.*y1)`, which is twice the area of the triangle with vertices (0,0), (x1,y1), and (x2,y2). Dividing this quantity by the base of triangle, `sqrt((x2-x1).^2+(y2-y1).^2)`, yields its height.

Also, putting 1000000 samples into mere 10 bins is a waste of information: you get a crude histogram for all that effort. Better to use `hist(length,100)`.

Finally, your method of selecting two points through which to pass a line does not take them from the uniform distribution on the disk. If you want uniform distribution over the disk, use

```
r1 = sqrt(rand(1,1000000));
r2 = sqrt(rand(1,1000000));
```

because for a uniformly distributed point, the **square** of the distance to the center is uniformly distributed in [0,1].

Finally, I've no idea why you square in `prob = (flag/1000000)^2`.

---

Here is your code with aforementioned modifications.

```
r1 = sqrt(rand(1,1000000));
teta1 = 2*pi * rand(1,1000000);
x1 = r1 .* (cos(teta1));
y1 = r1 .* (sin(teta1));

r2 = sqrt(rand(1,1000000));
teta2 = 2*pi * rand(1,1000000);
x2 = r2 .* (cos(teta2));
y2 = r2 .* (sin(teta2));

distance = abs(x1.*y2-x2.*y1)./sqrt((x2-x1).^2+(y2-y1).^2);
length = 2*sqrt(1-distance.^2);

hist(length,100)
flag = 0;
for check = length
if( check > sqrt(3) )
flag = flag + 1;
end
end

prob = flag/1000000;
```